# Needing to get only part of the ID everything after last underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to efficiently get everything after the last underscore or perhaps everything after and including "chk"

Example is

```
GridView1__ctl2_chkOut  --> I want ONLY  chkOut
```

Or

```
GridView1__ctl2_chkYes2  --> I want ONLY  chkYes2
```

Or

```
GridView1__ctl2_chkNo2  -->  I want ONLY chkNo2
```

I will always know the ID  e.g.   GridView1__ctl45_chkNo2

I know that a substring is probably not the best way to handle it unless it was used along with something else that counted characters till finding last underscore or perhaps it found the "chk" part  etc..  not sure 
var res = str.substring(1, 4);

**HTML**

```
   <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkOut" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkOut" checked="checked" class="out">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkYes2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkYes2" checked="checked" class="yesno">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkNo2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkNo2" class="yesno">
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and access the last item in the array

```js
var ids = ['GridView1__ctl2_chkOut'
  , 'GridView1__ctl2_chkYes2'
  , 'GridView1__ctl2_chkNo2'
];

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  var splat = ids[i].split('_');
  console.log(splat[splat.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Replace is unnecessary.

Comment: This will come in handy because I think I am going to pass all 3 of them to a ajax call to update a db table

Answer (score 3):

I would access the "id" attribute using jQuery and then split the value:

```
var r = $('.yesno').attr('id').split('_').pop()
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqN2G/1/)

Comment: ^1, this is actually the best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
str='GridView1__ctl45_chkNo2';
let index = str.lastIndexOf('_');
let result = str.substr(index + 1);
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75fc4uau/

Comment: This is a nice solution because it handles the string as a string, it doesn't convert it unnecessarily to an array.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you everything from last underscore to the end of string.

```
var res = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('_')+1, str.length);
```

If you want to filter further i.e. anything before chk

```
var chkRes = res.substring(res.lastIndexOf('chk'), res.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = "GridView1__ctl2_chkOut".split("_");
arr[arr.length - 1]; // gives chkOut
```

Comment: How does this work?   You split on _  , then  length - 1      This code works and I will probably use it because I don't need the loop from AmmarCSE , but my question certainly did come across a bit like I needed all at once

Comment: split() function creates an array of string from the provided string, seperated by string passed as the function's first parameter(e.g underscore). Then, when you get the last item of that array, you get whatever is in the string after the last underscore. @AmmarCSE actually did the exact same thing, just looped through all the example strings you have provided in your question.

Comment: thx,  that helps a lot.   I think I do need to use OP answer with loop after all because I need to be calling up ajax to send all the values to a db table