# Needing to get only part of the ID everything before the last underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Realizing now that I also want to separate out and get all the characters BEFORE  "chkOut"

```
GridView1__ctl2_chkOut
```

So I want  `GridView1__ctl2_`

My original question:

[Needing to get only part of the ID everything after last underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597499/needing-to-get-only-part-of-the-id-everything-after-last-underscore)

The LOOP answer on the other question I like, but I don't know the full ID names.

```
<td>
    <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkOut" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkOut" checked="checked" class="out">
</td>
<td>
    <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkYes2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkYes2" checked="checked" class="yesno">
</td>
<td>
    <input id="GridView1__ctl2_chkNo2" type="checkbox" name="GridView1:_ctl2:chkNo2" class="yesno">
</td>
```

Comment: Use [`^.*_`](https://regex101.com/r/lP3pB8/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = 'GridView1__ctl2_chkOut';
console.log(str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf('_')+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var text = "GridView1__ctl2_chkOut";

var firstHalf = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
var secondHalf = text.substring(firstHalf.length, text.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "GridView1__ctl2_chkOut"
str.split('chkOut')[0]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.